# How to get an error by using deleteOne method of Mongoose with a key after deleting one document with the same key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, error-handling, mongoose-deleteone

I have got stuck in a problem about deleteOne method of Mongoose.

The problem is as follows:

1. deleted a document by using deleteOne() with a key.
2. tried to delete the same document by using deleteOne() with the same key again, and then the method didn't return any error.

[The code that I wrote is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93Jkf.png)

Is it possible to get an error somehow?

I would be grateful if you could solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For further read:
This is also present in MongoDB documentation
[MondoDb documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/deleteOne/#:~:text=The%20deleteOne()%20method%20uses,and%20deletes%20the%20first%20match.)
Just putting it here for others to reference

Answer (score 3):

Mongodb (npm used by you mongoose) returns following with *deleteOne* when deleting a document with key and it exists:

```
{ "acknowledged" : true, "deletedCount" : 1 }
```

In case, when you delete the same document which was already deleted it returns:

```
{ "acknowledged" : true, "deletedCount" : 0 }
```

So, modify your code as below:

```
await Post.deleteOne({_id: postId}, (err, d) => {
    if (err) return res.status(400)
    if (d.acknowledged && d.deletedCount == 1)
        console.log("Deleted Successfully")    // Use your response code
    else
        console.log("Record doesn't exist or already deleted")    // Use your response code
})
```

Mongo Shell Output for reference:

```
> db.post.deleteOne({"_id" : ObjectId("5e8478d86c193bc19f5e4112")})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "deletedCount" : 1 }
> db.post.deleteOne({"_id" : ObjectId("5e8478d86c193bc19f5e4112")})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "deletedCount" : 0 }
```