# post() callback function for deleteOne doesn't give the document object || Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

```js
ClubSchema.post('deleteOne', {document : true, query : true}, function (doc) {
    console.log('Running');
    console.log(doc);
    let club_id = doc._id;
    console.log(club_id);
});
```

Output (Whenever the deleteOne() function is called) :

```
Running
{acknowledged: true, deletedCount: 1}
undefined
```

I tried all variations and tweaking with the function - with and without the options parameters, checking out the second parameter that's passed into the callback function, etc. - but to no avail. I even tried the `this` keyword, but again it's undefined as well.

The following was the callback function definition in the package files :

```js
type PostMiddlewareFunction<ThisType = any, ResType = any> = (this: ThisType, res: ResType, next: CallbackWithoutResultAndOptionalError) => void | Promise<void>;
```

And the example in the documentation gives the following example :

```js
schema.post('deleteOne', function(doc) {
  console.log('%s has been deleted', doc._id);
});
```

I tried replicating this same example, but the doc parameter passed into the function seems to be different from the one here.

Anything that I'm missing here ?

I have the same above post posted on [github issues](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/13730#issue-1848517007)

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62615433/21972629) help?

Comment: @jQueeny It's one solution to it, but it will be redundant if we have multiple deleteOne calls at multiple places. A way to implement this middleware is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deleteOne,deleteMany returns the the database operations result,
use removeOne or findOneAndDelete method instead if you want to return deleted document